# Github - Failure: The Travis CI build failed

Tags: github

I have pulled a request.

I have changed two files and committed the pull request.

After committer, I have received like,

> This branch has no conflicts with the base branch

But, I am getting like

> Failure: The Travis CI build failed

What is this issue about? Can my change merged by the owner?
Or
Will this make issue for the owner?
[image]

Comment: If you click `Details` for that status check, it will take you to the Travis CI build that is failing.

Comment: @osowskit When I do that, I see a massive log - do you know of a way to view just the errors?  Haven't found that yet.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new SO question with the log file and mentioning Travis ci and whatever language you are using.

Comment: I have the same question. Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Those two messages you've mentioned are not related
(`This branch has no conflicts with the base branch` and `Failure: The Travis CI build failed`), don't focus there.

Your build is failing, so something is wrong (unit tests?) as @osowskit said. Please paste your logs from travis (yes, it probably will be a huge wall of text) so we can point the right direction to look further.